# Gradle - IntellIJ - BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

Tags: github, gradle, repository, build.gradle

I just downloaded repository from GitHub and immediately got this error:

```
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 

C:\Users\hamzi\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init.gradle' (C:\Users\hamzi\.gradle\caches\8.0\scripts\asuznngwu6usyi0wiwvf77d4m).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[image: Error]

I tried to change the Java Version in project from **17 to 11**, but after that, the IntellIJ Idea FULLY stopped working (couldn't open the program). I tried to change dependencies, it didn't help either. Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. If you have the same problem, **you need to change the version of Gradle**; it is not necessary to change the version of JDK.

Comment: Is there a version this needs to be updated to? Also, can you link to the image you wanted to reference, or to a page containing the image?

Answer (score -1):

In android/build.gradle

i changed buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0" to buildToolsVersion = "32.0.0" save and run my problem solved as build success